# I built a Flask app on a Windows PC but now want to work in macOS. Why does, "flask run," produce the error: "zsh: command not found: flask"

Tags: python, github, flask, pycharm, zsh

I built a Flask app following an [online Flask tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world), on a Windows 10 PC. I created a repository for it on GitHub, and I am now trying to work with the code on my Mac. While I was building the app, I just open the Terminal in PyCharm, type in, `flask run`, and the server would start.

On my Mac in PyCharm, I use the `Get from Version Control` option, clone the repository from GitHub, and the project files download to, `/Users/myUserAccount/PycharmProjects/`. The project opens, but now, when I type into the PyCharm Terminal,  `flask run`, I get the error message: `zsh: command not found: flask`.

I do as much research as I can before asking, and I've read several SO articles about this error message. I def. seems to have to do with my Mac using Z Shell, but my programming knowledge is not deep enough to fully understand how to work around this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my requirements.txt file...

```
alembic==1.3.2
Babel==2.8.0
blinker==1.4
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
dominate==2.4.0
elasticsearch==7.5.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Babel==1.0.0
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2
Flask-Moment==0.9.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
guess-language-spirit==0.5.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
Mako==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
PyJWT==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-dotenv==0.10.3
python-editor==1.0.4
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
six==1.13.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.12
urllib3==1.25.8
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.16.0
WTForms==2.2.1
```

When I run `echo $PATH`I get this...

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools
```

I have a feeling the Path is the issue. I do not really understand how "Path" fits into programing. I just know that when I Google search for articles on Path and on Shell... none of the articles seem to help me understand my specific issue(s).

Comment: Virtual env? How does your `pip freeze` look like? What do you have in your System PATH?

Comment: Have you set an environment variable? `export FLASK_APP=hello.py`

Comment: @ponkape - I added the requirements.txt and the Path to this original question.

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik - I have FLASK_APP=myappname.py in a .flaskenv file, which has worked on the Windows PC just fine.